# Building responsive single-page web app using laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How am I supposed to use laravel with vue to develop a responsive single-page web app?

I am working on a project which requires laravel vue.

Comment: I recommend creating an API in Laravel and separate Vue SPA app.

Answer (score 2):

1. make Vue app inside Laravel using [Laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix).
2. make each of FE(Vue) and BE(Laravel) in a separate subdomain, then connect them via API.

I prefer the second approach.